# How can I use Sandcastle Help File Builder to generate documentation without documentation source?

Tags: documentation, sandcastle

I want to be able to generate help documentation from existing topic files (.AML) using  Sandcastle. I use Sandcastle Help File Builder to assist the with the configuration and generatation of the documentation.

I do not want to publish any code documentation, however, if I do not specify a Documentation Source (e.g., project, solution, dll, exe, etc.) then the build fails.

How can I configure Sandcastle Help File Builder such that I can generate documentation without exposing the code documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is accomplished by enabling the [Additional Content Only Plugin.](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/e031b14e-42f0-47e1-af4c-9fed2b88cbc7.htm)  This can be found in PlugInConfigurations in the Project Properties.  Simply adding this plugin produces the desired output.